# iOS - Webservice updating process and localization

Tags: ios, web-services, cocoa-touch, localization

My app gets updated data from a webservice. However I only want my app to download that data if it is really updated. What is the best way to deal with this? Should I have a file on the webservice only containing what is the latest version? Then the app would download that file and parse the version and compare it to what is currently installed, if version is newer than installed app would download the new version?

I'm going to save this data to the application support folder. How do I deal with localization of the files? I will have a Swedish and English version of the files. The files will be json formatted. Are there any file naming conventions I need to follow so that the app will use the correct localized versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version your data. Add an updateCheck api to the server where the app sends it's current version to the server and receives back either the new update or an "all up to date" notification. As long as the file namespace can handle the localized names, whatever convention you come up with for localization should be fine. For ease of runtime selection, it might be easiest to have a "se" and "en" subdirectory for the localized versions.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample on how to save the two different files and how to access the localized resource after they have been saved?